Treat array as if it were a flexible array member? Undefined behavior?
Ideally, I want to have something like this:
struct S {
  int other_member;  // not relevant to question
  // ...
  union {
    void *ptr;
    char buf[];
  };
};

That is, a struct with either a pointer to external storage, or intrusive storage of data.  But standard C doesn't allow unions to have flexible array members.  (My reading of the standard is that it doesn't explicitly forbid it, but adds flexible array members as a special case only for structures.)
But what if I did this instead:
struct S {
  int other_member;  // not relevant to question
  // ...
  union {
    void *ptr;
    char buf[ sizeof(void*) ];
  };
};

When I want to use intrusive storage, I would do this:
if ( buf_size < sizeof(void*) )  // just in case
  buf_size = sizeof(void*);
struct S *s = malloc( sizeof(struct S) - sizeof(void*) + buf_size );

then read/write data to s->buf of some object of type T where sizeof(T) ≥ sizeof(void*).
Is that OK?  Or undefined behavior?
(I believe before flexible array members were added to C, declaring buf[1] and just malloc'ing a bigger size were common practice.)

Notes:

I want to use only standard C, not extensions.
struct S is a node. There are many nodes. If one is intrusive, they all are and their data sizes are all equal.  The size is stored elsewhere.


char buf[ sizeof(void*) ]; is just a plain old array so you can't write out of bounds of it. Or you've just re-invented the old "struct hack" with all the UB that comes with it. Which flexible array members was the solution for.

@Lundin I know it's the same struct hack. I even said so in my parenthetical comment. I also know that generally writing beyond the bounds of an array is UB. However, the C committee has often made decisions to grandfather common practice so as not to break old code, so perhaps the old struct hack was grandfathered — which is why I'm asking my question.

The C standard requires a struct to have another member before the flexible array member. For a union, there are no members before other members.

@IanAbbott There is a member before the flexible array member. Here, it's denoted by the //.... The other members aren't relevant to my question, hence their omission.

@PaulJ.Lucas  What comes before the union is irrelevant for its legality.

@IanAbbott I know. My proposed work-around does not use a flexible array member, so this whole digression about the rules for flexible array members is irrelevant.

@PaulJ.Lucas With the workaround, you would also need to take care if the buffer needs more alignment than the struct.

I doubt there is a nice solution for this. Two not quite nice solutions are: (a) Just declare the structure with a char buf[] flexible array member, no funny union stuff. When using it for the void *, copy the bytes into it and out of it with memcpy, as in void *temp; memcpy(&temp, MyStructure.buf; sizeof temp);. A good compiler should optimize the copy into a simple load instruction, especially if you mark the buf member to be aligned for a void *…

… (b) Use a void *buf[] flexible array member. Then, when using it for void *, you simply have MyStructure.buf[0] or *MyStructure.buf. When using it for bytes, you can use again memcpy into or out of it or, to reference bytes in it, use ((char *) MyStructure.buf)[i], since C allows aliasing any object type using a character type. Using macros or helper functions could make some of this less ugly at the use points.

@EricPostpischil Yeah, to me, (b) is probably best and I don't have to worry about UB. (Of course, I'm still curious as to whether my original proposal actually is UB.)

Yes, the original is undefined behavior. When the compiler sees some code accessing MyStructure.buf[i], where buf has been defined as char buf[sizeof(void *)];, then it may assume 0 ≤ i < sizeof (void *). Code could be optimized on that basis. E.g., the compiler could turn an indefinite loop into a selection of some fixed cases, where it loads at most sizeof (void *) bytes. And if the loop is written, say, for (i = 0; i < n; ++i), the compiler could also deduce n < sizeof (void *) and spread the constraint to further code.

I don't think that's valid C99 or GNU. Might be helpful if we could see what you are using it for.

@PaulJ.Lucas, "read/write data to s->buf of some object of type T" is a problem when the alignment needs of some object exceed those of the union.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I could easily include max_align_t _align in the union. But that's not the point of my question.

One possibility is to make the whole union a flexible array member:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct S {
  bool indirect;
  size_t length;
  union {
    void *ptr;
    char elem;
  } u[];
};

struct S *alloc_s_indirect(size_t len) {
  struct S *s = malloc(sizeof(*s) + sizeof(s->u->ptr));

  if (s) {
    s->indirect = true;
    s->length = len;
    s->u->ptr = calloc(len, sizeof(s->u->elem));
    if (!s->u->ptr) {
      free(s);
      s = NULL;
    }
  }
  return s;
}

struct S *alloc_s_direct(size_t len) {
  struct S *s = calloc(1, sizeof(*s) + len * sizeof(s->u->elem));

  if (s) {
    s->indirect = false;
    s->length = len;
  }
  return s;
}

void free_s(struct S *s) {
  if (s) {
    if (s->indirect) {
      free(s->u->ptr);
    }
    free(s);
  }
}

char *get_s_buffer(struct S *s) {
  return s->indirect ? s->u->ptr : &s->u->elem;
}

int main(void) {
  struct S *s1 = alloc_s_direct(42);
  struct S *s2 = alloc_s_indirect(23);

  free_s(s1);
  free_s(s2);
}


Since OP's goal includes "read/write data to s->buf of some object of type T where sizeof(T) ≥ sizeof(void*)", it makes sense to be sure .u is aligned for all standard alignments - maybe with alignas (max_align_t)?

Huh. Yeah, something like that should work. I think it's between your answer and Eric's suggestion.

@chux It's just a prototype to get the idea across, but sure. Members of the desired element types could be added to the union, perhaps with a dummy member of type max_align_t to ensure that it can be used for non explicitly included types.

As already noted, unions cannot have flexible array members and declaring char buf[sizeof(void*)]; would just give a plain array which we cannot access out of bounds. Declaring some array char buf[1] was known as the old school "struct hack", which was a wildly unstable hack relying on undefined behavior, used prior to C99 flexible array members.

I probably shouldn't even mention it since it is a bad solution, but there is an obsolete GNU C feature of declaring an array with size zero, which was the fix before C99. So by using non-standard C (gcc -std=gnu17) you would actually be able to do this:
[Bad solution 1]
union
{
  void *ptr;
  char buf[0];
};

...

struct S* s = malloc(sizeof *s + n);


However, the best solution is as often to revisit the specification and fix it, since it's the source of the problem here:

That is, a struct with either a pointer to external storage, or intrusive storage of data.

It's widely recognized as bad practice to use a shared memory area for unrelated purposes (see MISRA C et al). A memory area should not either be a pointer or an array, that's very likely a senseless design.
[Good solution]
So a better solution here would simply to declare a struct with a pointer set to NULL when not used. And after it a flexible array member, which is used in case the pointer is NULL.
You can even have the pointer point at the flexible array member if you wish. That's actually quite nice because that array will be loaded into the same cache line as the rest of the struct, so pointing there will likely be faster than pointing at some externally allocated memory.
At this point we might start to realize that the pointer is in fact useless. Why would we point at data allocated a few bytes further down in memory when we can just access that memory? We would probably rather just have a size member instead, telling the allocated size of the flexible array member. That's fast, readable, maintainable code. Good programmers strive to make code simpler and not to make it more complex.
struct S {
  int other_member;
  size_t buf_size;
  char buf[];
};


[Bad solution 2]
So what if you have an actual need to access data stored elsewhere? In that case are you sure if the external data shouldn't just be another struct? In which case the correct way of accessing the right data is to have a struct pointer. Or if we stubbornly insist on making things needlessly complicated for the heck of it, a union:
typedef union
{
  struct S* local;
  struct X* external;
} complicated_t;


I've added notes to my question. "Good Solution" doesn't allow for external storage, so it's a non-starter. For "Bad solution 2": the external data must be void*. S is generic and can not know anything about said data except its size. The best answer (so far) is by Eric.

@PaulJ.Lucas I still insist that the correct solution is to revisit your program design and make changes there. This is all kind of an "XY problem" where you need some artificial, complex structure for a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place, if the program design was sound.

The "X" is for a set of nodes in a data structure that must be generic, i.e., hold any kind of user-specified data. I want said data structure to allow the user to store either external data not managed by the data structure — or — to store data internally as part each node to save on a malloc call (i.e., rather than 1 malloc for the data and 1 malloc for the node, just do 1 malloc for both). The latter also has better locality since the data will be on the same cache line as its node.

@PaulJ.Lucas As mentioned in the answer "You can even have the pointer point at the flexible array member if you wish" if it is heap allocation run-time speed you are worried about. That smells of pre-mature optimization but yeah it would be an itty bit more cache-friendly. And I still don't get it why you can't do that on the struct pointer level. Either point at a local struct or an external struct.

@PaulJ.Lucas Also, programmers tend to get lost in their optimization attempts. In the use-case "external data", is your program fast enough to access the data which will probably not get neatly loaded into cache? If so, your program meets the real-time requirement. Optimizing the case "local data" leads to no real-world performance gain because your program must still at all times be able to handle the worst-case scenario "external data" and if it does, it is by definition fast enough.

The pointer pointing at the internal data wastes 8 bytes per node. For a particular set of data, it'll either all be external or all local. I want to give the user the choice. BTW, once implemented, I plan to perf analyze it to see what the differences actually are. But first I need an implementation.
